# How Can I organize data in a binary file?

Tags: c++, arrays, binaryfiles

I am trying to organize matrices in a binary file, and I am not quite sure how to go about doing it. I have been successful in writing a 2d array to a binary file, and reading that data back, but I fear that I am only writing one long line to my binary file, and then reading it back into a 2d array. But, then again, I am not completely sure how a binary file works so I may be wrong.
I want to organize my binary file into a chart of arrays. Is this possible?
I apologize if I am explaining myself poorly. If so please leave a comment so that I may try to better illustrate what I am trying to do.

Thank you!

Comment: Is there any reason why you are using a 2D array instead of a plain flat one? It would be much easier to unify the data this way.

Comment: I am trying to create a procedurally generated 10X10 tile where every index will hold either a 1 or a 0. You're saying it would be easier if I organize the binary file for 1d arrays and then read them as if they were 2d arrays?

Comment: Files are array of bytes. In that way all files are binary files. It just so happens that the bytes in a so called _text files_ can directly be represented as ASCII characters. You should be using those in combination with the fstream.

Comment: @Bartholomew I think it would be easier for you to wrap a 1D array in a structure that would behave the same as a 2D one. In other words, a structure where you could access array elements by (x, y) coordinates using the well-known (y * width + x) formula internally. That way, it would be a lot easier to write the data to the file.

Comment: @Ron The reason why I do not want to use a text file (or at least, why I don't think I want to use a text file) is because I will be writing the matrices in a random order but I want them in order, and I don't want to have to rewrite the file every time I do this. But I may be mistaken. Thank you for the responses!

Comment: If your numbers occupy more than one byte, you will need to consider *Endianess*.  Mirrored data from a Little Endian platform will not be compatible with a Big Endian platform.

Comment: @JérémiP. That sounds good, like it would work. But how can I write to the file on a new line, or the next y coordinate? This is what I'm not sure of.

Comment: You may want to store your data in ASCII text if you need to port the data to other platforms.  Also consider using an existing data file format like XML.

Comment: Reminder:  don't store pointers in a binary file.  The OS can load your program anywhere in memory, so a pointer value from one invocation may not be valid on the next invocation.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews Thank you for your response. The reason I am hesitant about using an ASCII text file is because I will be writing the matrices in a random order but I want them in order, and I don't want to have to rewrite the file every time I do this.

Comment: @Bartholomew The data of each tile (if more than 1) would be on a single line (no matter what the y value is). Also consider what Thomas said.

Comment: @JérémiP. I most definitely will. I believe I understand now. I will have to keep track of the "y" coordinate by counting the digits, and incrementing "y" every time a certain amount has been counted. Is this correct? Also, is data written to a binary file always kept on a single line?

Comment: @Bartholomew No, you just have to read the whole line and copy the values directly to the internal 1D array of your structure. It's your structure that will interpret the data accordingly (using the formula I given).

Comment: @JérémiP. How can I write onto a new line in my file?

Comment: @Bartholomew By writing '\r\n' (Windows) or '\n' (Unix) before your new line (or simply std::endl).

Comment: @JérémiP. Okay. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Here some advice on how to make your serialization easier.

1. For a matrix, use a plain array.
2. Encapsulate your array in a class and give it an interface that looks like a matrix.
3. Serialize/deserialize the plain array easily.

Gist:

```
class MyMatrix {
private:
    std::vector<T> myData;
public:
    MyMatrix(int nelems);
    T & operator()(int row, int col);
    T & operator()(int row, int col) const;
```

};

Usage:

```
MyMatrix<int> m(200);
m(row, col) = 27;
...
serialize(m);
```

The serialization would be only serializing the std::vector (a pointer to n elems of type T actually). You can also use a plain `T *` plus `new` if you want and your Matrix is not resizeable.